# SQL Server - Add results of a SELECT query to an existing table

Tags: sql-server

I currently have a table in SQL Server called `masterTable`. What I'd like to do is to add a new column to this table called `report_Date`.

I would like to store the results of a `SELECT` query in the `report_Date` column. The query works fine (it converts a `nvarchar` into a desired date format). What I can't do is append the results to the column.

My query:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(varchar(10), CAST(FileName AS date), 103) AS FileName 
FROM dbo.masterTable
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: A column called `FileName` which actually has a date stored as an `nvarchar`? That seems all kinds of wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then

```
UPDATE dbo.masterTable SET
 report_Date = CONVERT(varchar(10), CAST(FileName as date), 103)
```